# Dax measure formatting issue

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to format the CalcType = 1 and CalcType = 2 by using "FORMAT" function and it does work on the values but it creates a new issue and starts showing all the subheaders under each header with blank values. Please see my Dax measure.

```
Actual = VAR CalcType = SELECTEDVALUE(HeaderPL[CalcType])
               VAR DisplayDetailCode = SELECTEDVALUE(HeaderPL[Detail])
               VAR isSubHeaderVisible = ISFILTERED(DimAccountsPL[Subheaders])
               VAR Result = SWITCH(TRUE(),  
                            isSubHeaderVisible=TRUE() && DisplayDetailCode = 0 ,Blank(), 
                            CalcType=1 ,[1 Final Display Value Actual],
                            CalcType=2 ,[Running Total Actual],
                            CalcType=3 ,FORMAT([% of Running Total Actual],"0%;(0%);-")
                            )
               RETURN Result
```

Comment: check if `DisplayDetailCode` always = `0`

Comment: Hi @Mik

Thanks for the reply

No, I have two criteria for this, in my table. If it is "1" it should show the subheaders and if 0 then don't. So I added the criteria, if it is "0"  don't show the subheaders.

Comment: Hi, just to clarify do you use the same measure for getting values in your subholders? Do you use the same measure for subholders values and values in the columns/rows? Can you add a images of the result?